# Apache Camel: Assign Integer Value to group attribute of Tokenizer

Tags: apache-camel

This is my first post here finding a solution for the recent problem I came across. I have a problem assigning a property(key) value to the "group" value in tokenize element. We have properties place holder and we need read the value to be read from configuration file as this limit might change. We have tried the any kind attribute using Property Placeholder as mentioned [here](http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html#UsingPropertyPlaceholder-UsingpropertyplaceholdersforanykindofattributeintheXMLDSL) but it fails with unrecognised attribute error.

The version of Camel being used is 2.15.1.redhat-621084 with Spring DSL and the code is like below. Please let me know in case if more details are required.

```html
<split>
  <tokenize token="\n" group="7000"/>
    ...
```

We just want the above "group" value to be configurable. Any help on this or a quick workaround is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance, 
Shanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any way to configure group value too. So create this strange workaround. Maybe it would help you.

```
<route>
        <from uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1"/>
        <setBody>
            <constant>123;321;444;555;666;777</constant>
        </setBody>
        <setHeader headerName="tokenizeGroup">
            <simple>properties-location:group</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <split>
            <method bean="rt" method="createIterable"/>
            <log message="Tokenized: ${body}"/>
        </split>
</route>
```

Method createIterable looks like :

```
public Object createIterable(@Header("tokenizeGroup") int group, Exchange exchange){
    TokenizerExpression tokenizer = new TokenizerExpression();
    tokenizer.setGroup(group);
    tokenizer.setToken(";");
    Expression expression = tokenizer.createExpression(exchange.getContext());
    return expression.evaluate(exchange,Object.class);
}
```